# Are there logics with context dependent predicates?

Tags: logic

I was reading the book at https://github.com/rzach/forallx-yyc and they state that the following is false:

> It is both raining here and not raining here.

This got me wondering if there are logics where predicates changes meaning mid-sentence?

For example if the first "raining" means "raining" and the second "raining" means "not raining"?

Comment: Maybe temporal logic?  For example: "It is raining now, and at some time in the past, it was not raining."

Comment: Or modal logic?  Example: If you haven't looked outside recently, then you could say both "It's possible that it's raining" and "It's possible that it's not raining" and have both be correct.